# Generate a random date within a given range in anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I have an agent *Container*, which has a parameter *departure_date*. I want to generate random future dates for this parameter. The date should be between current date and next 30 days. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear whether your parameter is of type Date or double. I'll provide you with a solution for each case.

- **Date**

`departure_date = addToDate(date(), DAY, random()*30);`

- **Double** - assuming your model time unit is DAYS

`departure_date = time() + random()*30`

Comment: Thank you, the variable is of Date type and your solution solved the problem.